# How many transactions do we get when two threads visit a method with @Transactional at the same time?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, multithreading, transactional

Let's say that we have this code:

```
@Transactional
public String getUser(long id) {

    User user = userDao.getUserById(id);
    if(user == null) {
        user = new User();
        user.setXXX(XXX);
        userDao.insert(user);
    }   
}
```

Assuming that datasource is `mysql5`:

How many transactions do we get if two threads visit `getUser()` method at the same time? If the answer is two, then what is the relationship between the two transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Spring Documentation:

> The getTransaction(..) method returns a TransactionStatus object,
>   depending on a TransactionDefinition parameter. The returned
>   TransactionStatus might represent a new transaction, or can represent
>   an existing transaction if a matching transaction exists in the
>   current call stack. The implication in this latter case is that, as
>   with Java EE transaction contexts, **a TransactionStatus is associated
>   with a thread of execution**.

Which means that for every thread Spring will create a new transaction, unless there is already one existing for that thread.

When two threads enter this method, two separate transactions are created and there is no relation between them. There is no nesting or anything going here (that is a different scenario). The only case that i can think of where there would be any relation is when the Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW is used, but this is not the case here.

Comment: under @Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRE), When two threads enter this method at the same time, two separate transactions are created.Right?

Comment: on the other hand, about mysql database,When two threads enter this method at the same time, two separate transactions are created.Right?

Comment: The answer is yes to both of the above. This behavior is not database dependent

Comment: If you find my answer of value i would appreciate you voting it up or accepting it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How many transactions do we get if two threads visit getUser() method at the same time?

The answer to this depends on the connection factory and the database type.  If you are using a connection pool or otherwise creating two connections then each thread will get a separate transaction with the database.  The details here are highly dependent on your connection pool and database settings.

> If the answer is two, so what is the relationship between the two transactions?

This depends on what the database does with these transactions.  It is important to realize that transactions are not about mutex but are rather about database coherency.  To quote from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction):

> A transaction symbolizes a unit of work performed within a database management system (or similar system) against a database, and treated in a coherent and reliable way independent of other transactions. A transaction generally represents any change in database.

How the transactions interact depends highly on what type of transaction is created and what is being done inside them.  If you are asking if it is possible for 2 threads to lookup a `User` with the same id at the same time and then try and create the same `User` twice then the answer is definitively yes.

One problem with this is that both `userDao.insert(...)` calls might succeed but the 2nd one to commit its transaction (race condition alert) might throw some sort of unique constraint exception but that might at a AOP level and not in your code.